# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 while importing static library to other library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I got and IOS, Objective C project from client, and I'm suppose to add new features and refactor. Project uses CocoaPods. In podfile there is a private library from bitbucket, which require login. Client has sent me a email, that he doesn't have login, but that he will send me a source codes. And here is my problem. Imagine library A and library B(custom fork of BlocksKit). A is dependent and is using library B and Main project uses library A. So I built Library B as a static library and then import it in A. But I got (null): 18 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
here is log :

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BKControlWrapper._controlEvents in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIControl+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(UIControl+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BKControlWrapper._handler in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIControl+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(UIControl+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BKControlWrapper in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIControl+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(UIControl+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BKControlWrapper in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIControl+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(UIControl+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BKInvocationGrabber._target in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BKInvocationGrabber._invocation in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BKInvocationGrabber in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BKInvocationGrabber in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSInvocation+BlocksKit.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKObserver._observee in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKObserver._keyPaths in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKObserver._context in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKObserver._task in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKObserver._isObserving in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$__BKObserver in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$__BKObserver in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKBlockObservation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$__BKWeakAssociatedObject._value in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$__BKWeakAssociatedObject in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$__BKWeakAssociatedObject in:
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Intermediates/TAEssentials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o
    /Users/jozefmatus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAEssentials-fbdhitikjlcggqbtvzfisnljuull/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTAEssentials.a(NSObject+BKAssociatedObjects.o)
ld: 18 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I have already tried looking form #import "whatever.m", or looking into Compile Sources for duplicates without any luck. So I'm despaired.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed cocoapods onto your system?

Comment: Yes yes, im using cocoapods in other projects normally.

Comment: Have you compiled it using iOS device..this seems to be a simulator issue.

Comment: No I haven't because I don't have device right now. You think that on Device it would be OK?. Thank you

Comment: x86_64 errors are simulator specific errors.A cause may be that your included libraries aren't build to run on simulators

Comment: No no, it is build for x86_64...I have personally built it. And also checked with lipo -info

Answer (score 0):

Remove reference to the  .o library file  from the project and add it back to the project.. Sometimes this solves the problem you are having